# How to remove unwanted mesh generated with subdivision surface modifier

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I want to make a model for a game with Blender, right now I am making an escape pod for a spaceship, just the basic mesh structure that will have a texture (which I will figure out if there's any problems later), but here's the problem, I am getting an unwanted corner mesh when making the doorway into the pod.

Couldn't post a picture here, sorry

But I have tried making more cuts and they don't work when using them to cut down the mesh, here is the blend file: [image]

PS:(It is happening to all four corners of the doorway so it'll most likely work for all if it works with one)

Here's a blend without all the cuts if it makes it easier: [image] NOTE: The nose cone isn't done in this version!

Comment: It's best to add your .blend files to your question using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok I will remember that for next time

Comment: For posting pictures please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Ray Mairlot - I know how to, it's just a limit happened, cause I'm new to the community;
Dimali - Ok, I looked at it, I will close this, I just didn't find it the first time, sorry, but thanks

Comment: @how_to_LoL_u If you want a user to get notified of a comment you have to '@' them, e.g. '@RayMairlot'.